# Adding a style to custom text view in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-custom-view, android-styles

I have a CustomTextView, I used to add style to it using xml style attribute, but with compose I need to understand how to do it.
When using this :

```
   AndroidView( factory = { context->
                    RegularAmountTextView(ContextThemeWrapper(context,R.style.TextAppearance_MyTheme_Heading_Small ),null  ).apply {
                        text ="1234"
                }
                }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().wrapContentHeight() )
```

I get error: Infinite cycle trying to resolve '?attr/textColorHighlight': Render may not be accurate. in preview panel.
while on running on device I get:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 4: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010099 a=1}
                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:529)
                at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:4345)
                at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1340)
                at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1258)
                at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:108)
                at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:103)
```

Similar error only. If I remove the style then it works. Has Android team provided any solution for this.
Another question: On facing these errors I was thinking is using compose on production a wise decision, or we should wait till android team provides proper inter-portability.

Comment: You can use the inherited attribute to style it

Comment: you mean styling inside  RegularAmountTextView?

Comment: yes! have you tried it??